# Rails CKeditor not submitting data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I used the following statement to create a ckeditor:

`=  f.text_area  :message, :class=>'ckeditor', :ckeditor => {:language => "us"}`

if I use f.cktextarea as specified in `https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor`, I get only a normal text area.

and if I call .ckeditor() on the text area also I dont get one.

I get ckeditor only if I add ckeditor class to the text area.

But even if I have a ckeditor, the value isnt being submitted when I submit the form.

What should I do?

On inspection I get my text area as:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="40" id="email_message" name="email[message]" rows="20" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
```

followed by the ckeditor code...

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.cktext_area :message, :ckeditor => {:language => "us"} %>

    <script type='text/javascript' charset='UTF-8'>
      $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('form[data-remote]').bind("ajax:before", function(){
          for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.formSubmit').submit( function()
       {
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData(); 

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ck_bienban_1_luu.php',// url of phpcode save
            data: {
                data: data,
            },
            success: function() {
                // 
            },
            });

            return(false);
       }

    );
```

`.formSubmit` is class name of form,

`var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` this is data of textarea